# iOS 5 Camera not working like it did in 4.x

Tags: ios5

I have an app that worked perfectly fine w/ ios 4.x

the app works like this

1. launch app
2. click button that launches camera
3. take pic
4. click use
5. this takes you to another screen where you can tag the photo
6. etc...

Now when i click use button the app just freezes, there is no crash, no debug message nothing.  I have tried setting break points etc.. and I just dont know what else to try.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

--thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post another answer to make the answer clearer.

I just found the ( simple ) solution to this problem:

I replaced:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]  setRootViewController:self];
[[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

by:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

It worked on iOS 5 as it was working on iOS 4. I didn't test in iOS 4 yet but I think it's working similarily.

Please confirm me it's also working for you.

Answer (score 0):

If it is freezing, without a crash, then you might be stuck in an infinite loop somewhere.  As long as you are attached to the debugger when it is running, you can just pause the application while it is stuck, and it should give you some indication where it is getting held up.

Comment: or he could try using Shark also